# There is no option E-mail in SSRS data-driven subscription

Tags: reporting-services, subscription

I want to create data-driven subscription for my SSRS report.

I need to send reports by e-mail for users. But there is no option E-mail in "Specify how recipients are notified". Screenshot attached.

Why E-mail option doesn't exist here?

P.S.Using SSRS 2012, OS Windows 8.

[image]

Comment: My guess would be some kind of email service has to be set up first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure the Report Server has its E-mail Settings configured, e.g. in Reporting Services Configuration Manager:

[image]

Once this is set up the email option for subscriptions should become available.

Comment: If you set all this up and you still cant see it, make sure you have connected to the right instance of SSRS.